# Best way to do tryMax and tryMin in F#?

Tags: f#, seq

Suppose I have a `seq` and I want to return the largest if there are any elements or `None` otherwise. F# does not appear to have this built-in.

Here is my attempt:

```ml
let tryMax xs = 
  if Seq.isEmpty xs
  then 
    None
  else 
    Seq.max xs |> Some

let tryMin xs = 
  if Seq.isEmpty xs
  then 
    None
  else 
    Seq.min xs |> Some
```

- Are there any problems with this approach?
- Is there a built-in solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, here's `tryMinBy` as well:

```
let tryMinBy projection (items : seq<_>) =
    use e = items.GetEnumerator()
    if e.MoveNext() then
        let mutable minItem = e.Current
        let mutable minValue = projection minItem
        while e.MoveNext() do
            let value = projection e.Current
            if value < minValue then
                minItem <- e.Current
                minValue <- value
        Some minItem
    else
        None
```

---

The full suite:

```ml
module Seq

let tryMinBy projection (items : seq<_>) =
  use e = items.GetEnumerator ()

  if e.MoveNext ()
  then
    let mutable minItem = e.Current
    let mutable minValue = projection minItem

    while e.MoveNext () do
      let value = projection e.Current

      if value < minValue
      then
        minItem <- e.Current
        minValue <- value

    Some minItem
  else
    None

let tryMaxBy projection (items : seq<_>) =
  use e = items.GetEnumerator ()

  if e.MoveNext ()
  then
    let mutable maxItem = e.Current
    let mutable maxValue = projection maxItem

    while e.MoveNext () do
      let value = projection e.Current

      if value > maxValue
      then
        maxItem <- e.Current
        maxValue <- value

    Some maxItem
  else
    None

let tryMin (items : seq<_>) =
  use e = items.GetEnumerator ()

  if e.MoveNext ()
  then
    let mutable minItem = e.Current

    while e.MoveNext () do
      if e.Current < minItem
      then
        minItem <- e.Current

    Some minItem
  else
    None

let tryMax (items : seq<_>) =
  use e = items.GetEnumerator ()

  if e.MoveNext ()
  then
    let mutable maxItem = e.Current

    while e.MoveNext () do
      if e.Current > maxItem
      then
        maxItem <- e.Current

    Some maxItem
  else
    None
```

Comment: I appreciate expanding on my original answer below, where you may find the explanation & usage of this approach and an alternative. Though I'd recommend using `min` and `max` build-in functions as they may be better inlined/optimized and add readability.

Answer (score 7):

I think your approach is generally good. There was an answer that is now deleted that suggested to use `try/with` to prevent double-evaluation of the first item by catching the error for empty sequences, but that too can be expensive.

If you want to prevent double evaluation, you can use `Seq.cache`, or not use `Seq` at all (use `List` or `Array` instead). Or use fold, which iterates only once:

```ml
module Seq =
    let tryMin sq =
        sq
        |> Seq.fold(fun x y -> 
            match x with None -> Some y | Some x -> Some(min x y)) None
```

Usage:

```
> Seq.tryMin Seq.empty<int>;;
val it : int option = None

> Seq.tryMin (Seq.singleton 2L);;
val it : int64 option = Some 2L

> Seq.tryMin (seq { 2; 3});;
val it : int option = Some 2

> Seq.tryMin (seq { 2; -3});;
val it : int option = Some -3
```

A potentially faster method (I didn't time it), is to prevent the creation of `option` on each min- or max-calculation result, and at the same time preventing multiple iterations of the first item.

This *should* have much less GC pressure too ;).

```ml
module Seq =
    let tryMin (sq: seq<_>) =
        use e = sq.GetEnumerator()

        // this returns false if there is no first item
        if e.MoveNext() then
            let mutable result = e.Current
            while e.MoveNext() do
                result <- min e.Current result

            Some result
        else
            None
```

Usage:

```ml
> Seq.tryMin Seq.empty<int>;;
val it : int option = None

> Seq.tryMin (Seq.singleton 2L);;
val it : int64 option = Some 2L

> Seq.tryMin (seq { 2; 3});;
val it : int option = Some 2

> Seq.tryMin (seq { 2; -3});;
val it : int option = Some -3
```

Comment: It's very annoying that these aren't built in. I wonder if there's a proposal to add them. All four.

Comment: @BentTranberg, I agree. It's only mentioned here: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/940#issuecomment-761542798, but not as a suggestion to add it. Feel free to create a request in the F# suggestions repo here: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/.